# Asset field - saving assets with dynamic subfolder by categories not working consistently

Tags: assets, field, bug

I have two asset (image) fields in project entry type, both with the same setting and with different outputs… Anyone knows why? Thanks

My fields are:

- intro image field
- gallery image field

Both should save uploaded images into one folder named by project and it's two levels category:

```
projects/{category.one().slug}/{category.inReverse().one().slug}/{slug}
```

My categories might look like:

- accommodation

  - hotels
  - hostels
  - apartements
- bussiness

  - offices
  - stores
  - fastfood

So both image fields should be saved to one folder, example:

```
projects/accommodation/hotels/project_slug
```

But they usually ends in two separate folders:

```
projects/accomodations/hotels/project_slug (intro image)
projects/hotels/hotels/project_slug (gallery field)
```

Any idea what is the problem and why the dynamic field folder structure varies from field to field?

Comment: It depends on how you set it up and what you exactly do.. Objects in PHP are called by reference not by value, so when you change the `ElementQuery` `category.inReverse()` this will be changed for every other place... executing `category.one()` will return the same object because you execute the same query twice without changing the properies.You may want to use the clone function https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/functions.html#clone-object